# Why does makeindex input a spurious whitespace in footnote?

Tags: footnotes, indexing

I want to have an entry `$r_{\infty}$` in the index. When I mention it inside a footnote, there's an added whitespace (`$r_{\infty }$`). This results in multiple entries in the index.

Here is a minimal working code to reproduce the error:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{makeidx} 

\makeindex

\begin{document}

This is a sentence. And this sentence will have a
 footnote after its period.\footnote{This is a footnote,
 and we want to mention $r_{\infty}$.%
\index{$r_{\infty}$}\index{r@$r_{\infty}$}
Also the corresponding index entries have been done inside the footnote.
}% end footnote

\index{$r_{\infty}$}
\index{r@$r_{\infty}$}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

a footnote is a "moving argument" -- it is saved up to be used elsewhere.

when this happens, the contents of the footnote expand, and alphabetical control sequences end up with a space after their text.  (in other words, "`\infty`" ends up as "`\infty` ".)  ordinarily, this doesn't matter. but
when a term is written out for sorting into an index, the space *does* matter, because the index sort is simple ascii, and a string with an
extra space in the middle will sort separately.

the space can be avoided by preceding the affected control sequence by
`\string`.  (`\protect` doesn't work here.)  so your index entries in
this example can be entered (in the footnote) as

```
\index{$r_{\string\infty}$}\index{r@$r_{\string\infty}$}
```

and then they will sort together with the "normal" ones.

(i applaud your making two entries for this expression.  that will ensure
that someone can actually *find* the concept in the index.)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. This worked perfectly. I should have mentioned that I tried `\protect` and that it didn't work, and I didn't know about `\string`.

About making two entries for this expression: I usually do it, but with this particar entry I had "luck" that it didn't work. The second entry was part of my own little bug hunting session before posting here.